# What is the unit of the y-axis in the tensorboard loss functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, loss-function

I'm training a model through Tensorflow and evaluating via Tensorboard. This is my total loss function:

[image: Tensorboard total loss function]

Can anybody tell me what the unit of the y-axis is? At first instance I thought it would be a proportion, but then you wouldn't expect it starting from > 4. I understand this is a combination of the classification loss and the localisation loss, but even the classification loss alone starts from > 3.

[image: Tensorboard loss functions]

Im training trough the terminal command:

```
set NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 & set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 & python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path="V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config" --model_dir="V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Training" --alsologtostderr
```

And evaluating via the terminal command:

```
python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path="V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config" --model_dir="V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Training" --checkpoint_dir="V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Training" --alsologtostderr
```

This is the associated `.config` file:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2
# Trained on COCO17, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint
# Train on TPU-8
#
# Achieves 22.2 mAP on COCO17 Val

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 7
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.97,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.97,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.75,
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Model/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  batch_size: 32
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 25000

  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 20000
            learning_rate: 0.0003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Model/labelmap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Data/Train/train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Model/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "V:/Projecten/A70_30_65/Marterkist/Data/Train/test.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be in the code quite explicitly? Can you show the line where `total_loss` is calculated? Personally I would expect it to be a weighted sum.

Comment: Classification loss has no unit in general

Comment: @André I'm not sure where I can find the line where `total_loss` is calculated. I'm training via terminal commands and am only adjusting the `.config` file if I want different parameters, so I'm not actually writing python for my training. @Ming Ok, but the lower the lines the better the training is, right? Is there no way to say something about how the model performs in terms of absolute numbers? Something like it predicts the bounding boxes correctly in 98% of the images and the classifications in 87%.

Comment: Then what are the terminal commands you are running and what is the config? It is absolutely necessary to know what architecture you are training to answer your question.

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of your config is this:

```
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.75,
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
```

`classification_weight = localization_weight = 1` means that the total loss is just a sum of the classification and localization losses. `weighted_sigmoid_focal` classification loss is calculated as `-alpha*(1 - p)**gamma*log(p)`, where p is a class probability (see details in the article referenced by https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/SigmoidFocalCrossEntropy). It is hard to assign some easy-to-interpret sense to it. And `weighted_smooth_l1` localization loss is the same as [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss), which is not easily interpretable either.

All the above boils down to following: the absolute values you see don't have any easily understandable meaning. It is only relative changes that matter: does the loss increase or decrease etc.